# What solution of Eclipse to Install for Python

Tags: python, eclipse

```
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php
```

I saw a youtube video which tells to download and install Eclipse classic version but I couldn't find it on the Eclipse website. What solution do I install? I am beginner so sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having installed Eclipse classic (or any other version of Eclipse, for this matter), you can then install the PyDev module. (There are many online tutorials telling you how to do this. And the documentation can be found there: http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)

If you're looking for an IDE for Python, PyCharm is also very good and simple to install.Pycharm has a free, community edition).

Comment: Do I need to install Eclipse if I use PyCharm?

Comment: No they're separate programs.  BTW, when people are _really_ beginning with Python, they often use IDLE as their editor. It's one of the most simple of the lot. Easy to install, very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev plugin is very good for Eclipse.